# Splice enemy array to destroy enemy (js game)

Tags: collision-detection, javascript, html-canvas

I am currently working on a basic space invaders game. So far I have created the enemies, a main character, and a laser beam, collision detection between enemy and bullet, however when my bullet collides with my enemy sometimes one enemy is destroyed other times all or a couple of enemies are destroyed. Can you please inform me in what I am doing wrong.

```
this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
    var myleft = this.x;
    var myright = this.x + (this.width);
    var mytop = this.y;
    var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
    var otherleft = otherobj.x;
    var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
    var othertop = otherobj.y;
    var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
    var crash = true;
    if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
        crash = false;
    }
    return crash;
}
}

 function updateGameArea() {
var x, y;
for (y = 0; y < myObstacles.length; y += 1) {
    if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacles[y])) {
        var ctx = myGameArea.context;
         ctx.fillText("Game Over", 150, 150);
         myGameArea.stop();

    } 
 for (i = 0; i < bullets.length; i += 1) {
  if(myObstacles[y].crashWith(bullets[i])) {
   myObstacles.splice(myObstacles[y], 1);
}
}
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It looks like you've found a way to check your game piece against all obstacles. Have you tried doing the same thing for each bullet in the bullets array?

Comment: No not yet however I'll try that now. Does it work by checking crash detection then splicing the bullet.

Comment: You mean using array.splice to remove a bullet once it's hit something and expired, so that it no longer needs further simulation? That's certainly not forbidden to you.

Comment: I am not familiar with the splice function, can you explain a little more how I would be able to use it.

Comment: Actually I have made it work should I post the code to it as an answer.

Comment: You should indeed add an answer explaining your solution. The more description you add, the more helpful it can be to future users who have similar questions. :)

Comment: (I am curious though: if you're not familiar with the splice function, then what led you to use the word splice earlier? Are you using that word to mean something different?)

Comment: I had a feeling that you were referring to the removing of an object in an array using splice. So I checked then attempted to fix it and it worked :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved this is by splicing one enemy from the array of enemies when they collide with the bullet array. Then I would splice one bullet as well.
Below is the basic collision and removal of the enemy.

```
this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
    var myleft = this.x;
    var myright = this.x + (this.width);
    var mytop = this.y;
    var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
    var otherleft = otherobj.x;
    var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
    var othertop = otherobj.y;
    var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
    var crash = true;
    if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
        crash = false;
    }
    return crash;
}
}

  function updateGameArea() {
   var x, height, gap, minHeight, maxHeight, minGap, maxGap;
   for (y = 0; y < myObstacles.length; y += 1) {
        if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacles[y])) {
           myGameArea.stop();
           return;
       } 
     for (i = 0; i < bullets.length; i += 1) {
        if(myObstacles[y].crashWith(bullets[i])) {
          myObstacles.splice(y, 1);
          bullets.splice(i, 1);
         }
      }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you splice array, you remove the element. In your case, you are iterating over 'myObstacles' from 0 to length-1. When splicing arrray in such manner you need to iterate from length-1 to 0, so the indexes od 'myObstacles' are not changed.
Like this:

```
for (y = myObstacles.length - 1; y >=0; y--)
```

Then you continue to iterate bullets over the myObstacles[y], which might at that point already be removed. After splicing array, you need to **break** from the for loop.

Comment: I deleted the answer due to destroying all the enemies when destroying one, however i have found a new one.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use other iterable objects than arrays, they allow faster and easier deletion and accessing of elements, which makes them more suitable for handling collections of game objects. Check Map or Set API.

Comment: Myself, I would generally not recommend maps or sets for maintaining a local collection of objects for collision checks. They're usually considerably slower to iterate over. We can get fast removal with arrays by swapping the item to be removed to the last occupied index then decreasing our occupied index count.

Comment: @DMGregory that is genius if you don't care about order!